# Login if "Required User Actions" is existing

Tags: keycloak

i have the following problem if an existing keycloak user has one or more required user action.

We use the keycloak (3.4.2.Final) rest api to login into keycloak. But keycloak returns always code 401 (invalid_grant) if user locked out or any required user action exists. So i can not identify what the main problem is.

For lockout i don't need to verify user's password, with any password (calling attackdetection rest api) can i tell the end user that the account is locked BUT for the required user actions not the same, user has to login successfully then can i handle next steps.

For example UPDATE_PASSWORD:

Login with username/password -> Login successfully OR username/password validated -> handle user action -> update password -> user logged in

I would appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 5):

Just in case someone still cares about an answer:
You can update the User using keycloak's admin REST api.

```
PUT /auth/admin/realms/myrealm/users/myKeycloakUserId
{
    "id": "myKeycloakUserId",
    "createdTimestamp": 1547730135139,
    "username": "myusername",
    "enabled": true,
    "totp": false,
    "emailVerified": true,
    "firstName": "myfirstname",
    "lastName": "mylastname",
    "email": "myemail",
    "attributes": {
        "privacyStatementAcceptedDate": [
            "2019-01-17T13:02:15.189Z"
        ],
        "welcomeEmailDate": [
            "2019-01-17T13:02:30.370Z"
        ],
        "gender": [
            "female"
        ],
        "legalAgeConfirmedDate": [
            "2019-01-17T13:02:15.189Z"
        ],
        "termsAcceptedDate": [
            "2019-01-17T13:02:15.189Z"
        ]
    },
    "disableableCredentialTypes": [
        "password"
    ],
    "requiredActions": [],
    "notBefore": 0,
    "access": {
        "manageGroupMembership": true,
        "view": true,
        "mapRoles": true,
        "impersonate": true,
        "manage": true
    }
}
```

Someone might want to try to send only the requiredActions-property instead of all other values (since these should be retrieved first), but I don't know if this would actually work. I thought: Better safe than sorry, so I retrieve the data first and then I only set the requiredActions-property to an empty array and send it back.

If you are using the Java client library (keycloak-admin-client), you might do it like this:

```
org.keycloak.admin.client.Keycloak keycloak = KeycloakBuilder.builder()
    .serverUrl(KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_BASEURL))
    .realm(KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_REALM))
    .grantType(OAuth2Constants.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
    .clientId(KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_CLIENTID))
    .clientSecret(KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_CLIENTSECRET))
    .build();

final UserResource keycloakUserResource = keycloak.realm(
            configurationService.getValue(KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_REALM)).users().get(
            keycloakUserId);
//load the users user-representation from Keycloak
final UserRepresentation userRepresentation = keycloakUserResource.toRepresentation();
if (userRepresentation == null) {
    throw new Exception("Failed to load the UserRepresentation for the current User");
}

//adapt the user-representation
userRepresentation.setRequiredActions(Collections.emptyList());

//update user in Keycloak
keycloakUserResource.update(userRepresentation);
```

Comment: I was struggling to clear RequiredActions for User in Java Client Library, this helped me. :)